# Missing artifact org.jboss.fuse:jboss-fuse-full:zip:6.2.1.redhat-084 when it does show in local repository

Tags: maven, jbossfuse

I have a quickstart project that is failing to build with the following error.

```
Missing artifact org.jboss.fuse:jboss-fuse-full:zip:6.2.1.redhat-084
```

However, it does show in my local Maven repository, at least there is an entry.

[Here is a screenshot of my local repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYFav.png)

How can I clear this error?

Comment: There's only `*.lastUpdated` _marker_ which means that Maven couldn't download this artifact from any of the configured repositories.

Comment: Fuse 6.2.1.redhat-084 (GA) is very old Fuse version. But anyway - what's the quickstart you're trying to build? The quickstarts are part of `jboss-fuse-full-6.2.1.redhat-084.zip` file itself and this file is _the_ missing artifact.